# How to type a value outside the function

Tags: php, function, symfony

I want the value of $name outside of function so i can rename the zip file with it but how to do that?

this crawele method and i can not use the value outside the function

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
// go get the date from url
$url = 'https://hentaifox.com/gallery/58118/';

$resnm = $client->request('GET', $url);

$htmlnm = ''.$resnm->getBody();

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$res_name = $client->request('GET', $url);

$html_name = ''.$res_name->getBody();

$crawler_name = new Crawler($html_name);

$nameValues_name = $crawler_name->filter('.info > h1')->reduce(function (Crawler $node, $i){
    $name = $node->text();
    return $maname;
});

print_r($name);
$res = $client->request('GET', $url);

$html = ''.$res->getBody();

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$nodeValues = $crawler->filter('.gallery .preview_thumb')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
     $image = $node->filter('img')->attr('data-src');
     $imagerep = str_replace(array('//i2.hentaifox.com' , '//i.hentaifox.com','t.jpg'),array('https://i2.hentaifox.com','https://i2.hentaifox.com','.jpg'),$image);
     $zip = new ZipArchive();

     $my_save_dir = $name.'.zip';

     $zip->open($my_save_dir, ZipArchive::CREATE);

     $imgdownload = file_get_contents($imagerep);

     $zip->addFromString(basename($imagerep), $imgdownload);

     $zip->close();

});
```

help me out the value of $name to use it for nameing the zip file in $my_save_dir

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could that to functions... but you can. Looks a bit like Javascript, but it is PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php PS: It is not just a question of misspelling `$name` as `$maname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anonymous function can inherit data from it's surrounding scope with the `use` clause (see example 3 on https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
// $name has to be defined here.
$nodeValues = $crawler->filter('.gallery .preview_thumb')
                      ->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) use ($name) { // <-- the use
     //...
});
```

However, I have this weird feeling, that you'd be much better off when not using anonymous functions all the time, since you're not really adhering to the map-reduce principles. I guess this would work easier and good as well:

```
foreach($crawler->filter('.gallery .preview_thumb') as $i => $node) {
    // it's the same scope now
    // do whatever ...
}
```

However, why not open the Zip file *outside* the loop, and just add stuff inside the loop?!

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::filter() in C:\AppServ\www\gmanga\manga.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\AppServ\www\gmanga\manga.php on line 18

Comment: i replaced the last loop. but it works similarly with the first one. with the first one, you have to use $crawler_name and adapt what happens inside the loop though.

Comment: it gave me that error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in C:\AppServ\www\manga\index.php on line 16

Comment: @التقنيةtech then the error is certainly before the foreach. Since I can't see your (resulting/current) code, it's really hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a variable from outside, inside your [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) you need to do it like this:

```
$nodeValues = $crawler->filter('.gallery .preview_thumb')
                      ->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) use ($name) {
```

If you also want to be able to access any changes to the variable that have been made inside the anonymous function, you need to [pass it by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
$nodeValues = $crawler->filter('.gallery .preview_thumb')
                      ->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) use (&$name) {
```

You could also declare `$name` as a `global` variable, but this is generally considered a bad practice and you always need to keep track of them.